# divs side by side mobile responsive issue

Tags: html, css, resize, responsive

I have an html code which i want to display several divs side by side but no more than 2 per row
so i made it to perform exactly as i want on desktop but mobile seems to not get to work correctly, they look too small, the divs contains a series of infographics.

I know that the .float-child width 50% is defining its size for mobile too, but i don't know how to set responsive at this poit.

i'll appreciate any advice or recommendations! thanks!

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans&family=Oswald:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <style>
         .infogram-embed{
         border-style: solid;
         border-width: 1px;
         border-color:#C0C0C0;
         border-radius: 15px;
         overflow:hidden;
         position:relative;
         padding: 25px 0px 0px 3px;
         }
         h1 {
         padding: 25px 1px 1px 1px;
         font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif!important;
         }
         .float-container {
         padding: 20px;
         
         position: relative;
         height:0;
         
       
         }
         .float-child {
         width: 50%;
         float: left;
         padding: 20px;
        
         } 
  
       

         



      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="float-container">
      <div class="float-child">
         <div class="izquierda">
            <h1 style=font-size:20px>title1</h1>
            <div  
               class="infogram-embed"
               data-id=""
               data-type="interactive"
               data-title="title1"
               > </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="float-child">
         <div class="derecha">
            <h1 style=font-size:20px>title2</h1>
            <div
               class="infogram-embed"
               data-id=""
               data-type="interactive"
               data-title="title2"
               ></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="float-child">
         <div class="izquierda">
            <h1 style=font-size:20px>title 3</h1>
            <div
               class="infogram-embed"
               data-id=""
               data-type="interactive"
               data-title="title 3"
               ></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="float-child">
         <div class="derecha">
            <h1 style=font-size:20px>title4</h1>
            <div
               class="infogram-embed"
               data-id=""
               data-type="interactive"
               data-title="title 4"
               ></div>
         </div>
      </div>
  
    

<script>
  **/here goes js code which calls data for infographics/**
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Bootstrap CDN link to head of html file links provided here https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ after that utilize the bootstrap grid system info here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ so just add the class 'col-xs-12' to your 'float-container' div and then for every 'float-child' div add the class 'col-xs-6'

Comment: Thank you! bleepbloopblop123 
I have added boostrap and then simply used 

<div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xs-12">

For each div, it worked that way.

Comment: I mean

class ="row"

And then class="col12..." for each div

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, the simplest solution might be to use media query. Whatever size you want it to look like, you can adjust the width.

I set the screen to cover on mobile 75%, but you can change it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans&family=Oswald:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .infogram-embed {
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-color: #C0C0C0;
      border-radius: 15px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      padding: 25px 0px 0px 3px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      padding: 25px 1px 1px 1px;
      font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif!important;
    }
    
    .float-container {
      padding: 20px;
      position: relative;
      height: 0;
    }
    
    .float-child {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width:500px) {
      .float-child{
        width: 75%
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="float-container">
    <div class="float-child">
      <div class="izquierda">
        <h1 style=font-size:20px>title1</h1>
        <div class="infogram-embed" data-id="" data-type="interactive" data-title="title1"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="float-child">
      <div class="derecha">
        <h1 style=font-size:20px>title2</h1>
        <div class="infogram-embed" data-id="" data-type="interactive" data-title="title2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="float-child">
      <div class="izquierda">
        <h1 style=font-size:20px>title 3</h1>
        <div class="infogram-embed" data-id="" data-type="interactive" data-title="title 3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="float-child">
      <div class="derecha">
        <h1 style=font-size:20px>title4</h1>
        <div class="infogram-embed" data-id="" data-type="interactive" data-title="title 4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <script>
      ** /here goes js code which calls data for infographics/ **
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you are trying to make a responsive raw HTML...  I do not know... But since I am a __Bootstrap__ lover, i will make a suggestion  If you do not know __Bootstrap__, and want to build responsive pages, I would recommend that you try to use it.   But ```media queries``` will make the work!

Comment: you're saying that about Jony Corleone, right ? I am little confused :)

Comment: Hi.. Bootstrap, in my opinion, it´s the easier way to build responsive pages using HTML, CSS, and the classes from bootstrap.  You can try https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/